# Timezone offset with logstash / redis / ES

Tags: redis, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to configure logstash with redis and elasticsearch.

I have a problem with the @timestamp field.

The value of @timestamp is always the real event timestamp -2 hrs.

I have a shipper configured like this :

```
 input{ file {...}}


 filter{

    if [type]=="apachelogs"{

    grok{
            match => [ "message", "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"]
    }
      date {
            locale => "en"
            timezone => "Europe/Brussels"
            match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
      }
    }

}

output{ redis{...}}
```

and a logstash-indexer like this :

```
   input{ redis {...}}

   output { elasticsearch {...}}
```

The result of an event in ES looks like this :

```
 "@timestamp": "2014-05-21T13:29:53.000Z"
 ...
 "timestamp": "21/May/2014:15:29:53 +0200"
```

So as you can see there is always a 2hrs offset in the @timestamp and I can't figure out why. 
I've tried different things such as changing the timezone etc. without success.

Any idea about this one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this filter to change timezone. 
Change

> "@timestamp": "2014-04-23T13:40:29.000Z"

to

> "@timestamp": "2014-04-23T15:40:29.000+0200"

Try to use this filter

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
                event['@timestamp'] = event['@timestamp'].localtime('+02:00')
        "
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: how do you do if you live in a time zone which changes? (ex. Daylight Saving Time )

Answer (score 0):

`timezone` should be work.
What's wrong with your result? Values in following two fields indicate the same time point.

```
 "@timestamp": "2014-05-21T13:29:53.000Z"
 "timestamp": "21/May/2014:15:29:53 +0200"
```

Where Z stands for +0000.